# Pressing TAB when using tag auto-completion selects wrong tag

Tags: bug, status-norepro, tags, autocomplete

Here I'm entering the tag **`active-directory`**...

**Type `activ`**

[alt text http://alexangas.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2009/08/entertag2.png](http://alexangas.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2009/08/entertag2.png)

**Type the letters `-dire` to differentiate from `activerecord`**

[alt text http://alexangas.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2009/08/entertag3.png](http://alexangas.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2009/08/entertag3.png)

**Press <kbd>TAB</kbd> and wrong tag is inserted**

[alt text http://alexangas.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2009/08/entertag4.png](http://alexangas.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2009/08/entertag4.png)

*Possible resolution:* When pressing <kbd>TAB</kbd> a match against the currently entered text should be made.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's using the highlighted record. While the auto-complete could be made to be a little more intelligent, this certainly isn't a bug. The expected behavior is that if you press tab while a tag is highlighted, it will insert the highlighted tag...which is what this does.

Also, sidenote, I just tried this specific example, and it immediately switched to `active-directory` as soon as I hit the dash. Hitting tab selected `active-directory`.

Comment: That's interesting. Which browser are you using?

Comment: Chrome on WinXP. <3 Chrome.

Comment: Hmmm I'm on Firefox. Could be a perf issue.

Answer (score 2):

I have this problem periodically when I'm entering tags, but after the question posts, I'm unable to reproduce the issue.  Happens with IE7.  From time to time, it'll replace the first tag with the one I've tabbed to select.  Wish I had more info but it's very sporadic.

Answer (score 0):

The completion lag thing also happens to me (firefox and chromium). It makes [that other bug](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/39284/tag-completion-stays-open-after-space-has-been-typed-steals-enter-focus) more annoying.